# Merge two PDF file into one PDF using PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I want to merge two PDF file (300 mm width and 150 mm height each) into a SRA3 (450 mm width and 320 mm height) size page.
The first PDF will be inserted from top right and secoend PDF will be inserted from bottom right.

I tried https://github.com/myokyawhtun/PDFMerger but it just merge PDF one after another.

```
<?php
$attached_files = ['file1.pdf', 'file2.pdf'];

$pdf = new \PDFMerger;

foreach ( $attached_files as $attached_file ) {
   $pdf->addPDF( $attached_file, 'all' );
}

$file_name = 'orders-pdf-' . uniqid() . '.pdf';
$pdf->merge( 'download', $file_name );
```

Can anyone provide me some sample code?

Comment: This is not a trivial "merge" as you call it. You will need to create a completely new document. Best probably is to use something like `pdflib` (pdflib.com). You can also use image magick to place renderings (virtual screenshots) of the source documents on a target canvas, you this will always cause issues with the content resolution.

Comment: You can also do this with [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/fpdi). This way you don't have to worry about any resultion issues at all...

Answer (score 0):

Based on @arkascha comment, I built a function that combine two pdf into new pdf. I am sharing my code so anyone might find it useful.

```
function combinePdf( $filePath1, $filePath2 ) {
    // Each actual PDF size is (850.394 * 425.197) points
    // New PDF size need to be SRA3 (1275.8 * 907.2) points

    // Imagick default resolution if resolution not set
    $default_resolution = 72;
    // Multiplier to make resolution around 300
    $multiplier         = 4.167;
    // We found around 300 resolution looks like original image
    $resolution         = ( $default_resolution * $multiplier ); // 300

    // Read first PDF file
    $pdf1 = new \Imagick();
    $pdf1->setResolution( $resolution, $resolution );
    $pdf1->readImage( $filePath1 );

    // Read second PDF file
    $pdf2 = new \Imagick();
    $pdf2->setResolution( $resolution, $resolution );
    $pdf2->readImage( $filePath2 );

    // Build new SRA3 size PDF
    $newPdf = new \Imagick();
    $newPdf->setResolution( $resolution, $resolution );
    $newPdf->newImage( 1275.8 * $multiplier, 907.2 * $multiplier, "white" );
    $newPdf->setImageFormat( 'pdf' );

    // Calculate column offset of the composited PDF
    $x = ( 1275.8 * $multiplier ) - ( 850.394 * $multiplier );

    // Calculate row offset of the second composited PDf
    $y = ( 907.2 * $multiplier - ( $pdf2->getImageHeight() * 2 ) ) + $pdf2->getImageHeight();

    // Composite first and second PDF into new PDF
    $newPdf->compositeImage( $pdf1, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, $x, 0 );
    $newPdf->compositeImage( $pdf2, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, $x, $y );

    // Get image string
    $image = $newPdf->getImageBlob();

    return $image;
}
```